# WCF Web Service checking header values and parsing body

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, post

I've got a WCF Web Service running that accepts the following (REST):

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/StatusUpdate")]
string SMSUpdateStatus(Stream input);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ReceiveSMS")]
string SMSReceived(Stream input);
```

In order to authenticate the request, I need to combine each value passed in the POST (ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded), hash them with a particular key, and then compare it to a specific header value.

I had this working fine without the validation by using something like this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Dispose();
NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s));

string Val1= qs["val_a"];
string Val2= qs["val_b"];
```

I can't seem to figure out how to pull out a header value (which I need to do for my comparison) or split my NameValueCollection, which appears to simply hold my entire payload in a single key.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps trying:

```
OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders
```

would be of service? I haven't tested this, but I am interested to hear your results